# How to implement the mouse click for URLs at rich edit control

Tags: c++, c, winapi, richedit

I added a read-only rich edit 2.0 control to my dialog (code is using C windows API, the dialog is created by using function [DialogBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

At the dialog call back, at the WM_INITDIALOG, I add the following code to enable url detection and also enable the event ENM_LINK is sent to the parent dialog instead of the rich edit control itself:

```
LRESULT mask = SendMessage(hWndText, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0); //hWndText is rich edit control
SendMessage(hWndText, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, mask | ENM_LINK);
::SendMessage(hWndText, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, TRUE, NULL);
```

I had a little trouble to enable the url detection when dialog is initially launched (which seems a known issue or behavior since rich edit control would only enable url detection of modified text). However I worked around this issue by setting the dialog text again on every WM_PAINT event.

The code is generally working. I also implemented the following code to launch the URL at the browser when mouse is hovering over the url:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    plink = (ENLINK *) lParam;
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {   
        case IDC_DISPLAY_TEXT_2: //this is ID for my rich edit control
            szURL =m_strDisplay.Mid(plink->chrg.cpMin, plink->chrg.cpMax - plink->chrg.cpMin);          
            LaunchURL(szURL); //function to launch the url with default browser
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

It seems that I would get WM_NOTIFY event every time when I hovered the mouse over the url. However when I clicked on it, I always get same event as the mouse hover over.

Based on the structure of [ENLINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I should get more detailed NM event at the NMHDR structure, however the value plink->nmhdr.code is always 1803 which is not even NM_HOVER (its defined value is (NM_FIRST-13)  and NM_FIRST is (0U-  0U), so NM_HOVER value is 4294967283 on my 64 bit machine). I know that I am missing something here. Could someone shed some lights here? How can I get the mouse click event for the rich edit control?

Comment: See also [Detect click on URL in RichEdit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2480173/850848).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should capture the [EN_LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification. I implemented the following code. It enables a url link in a richedit control placed into the parent window, not into  a dialog. You could adapt it for your dialog, as well.

Consider beginning with the code:

```
case WM_NOTIFY: {
switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code) { //NMHDR structure contains information about a notification message.
        case EN_LINK: {
            ENLINK *enLinkInfo = (ENLINK *)lParam; // pointer to a ENLINK structure
```

then, if you choose to launch url on LBUTTONUP, you have to check the value contained in `enLinkInfo->msg` (remember to adapt it for your dialog, though)

```
 if (enLinkInfo->msg == WM_LBUTTONUP) {
// select all the text from enLinkInfo->chrg.cpMin to enLinkInfo->chrg.cpMax
// lauch the url

}
```

Besides, you can intercept WM_MOUSEMOVE:

```
if(enLinkInfo->msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
                ; // do nothing
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can see the added value -- checking `enLinkInfo->msg`. Good point.

Answer (score 4):

As the answer by @A_nto2 shows, to intercept a mouse click do:

```
case WM_NOTIFY: {
    //NMHDR structure contains information about a notification message.
    switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code) {
        case EN_LINK: {
            ENLINK *enLinkInfo = (ENLINK *)lParam; // pointer to a ENLINK structure
            if (enLinkInfo->msg == WM_LBUTTONUP) {
```

But the tricky part is to get the link that was clicked on.

One gets a "range" that was clicked on in the `enLinkInfo->chrg` of the type `CHARRANGE`.

An answer to [Detect click on URL in RichEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2480173/850848#2481863) suggests using the `EM_EXSETSEL` with the `enLinkInfo->chrg`. And then using the `EM_GETSELTEXT` to retrieve the text.

That works with auto-detected plain-text URLs (`EM_AUTOURLDETECT`).

A problem is with friendly name hyperlinks (i.e. those that have an anchor text different than the URL itself):

```
{\rtf1{\field{\*\fldinst{ HYPERLINK "https://www.example.com"}}{\fldrslt{Example}}}}
```

(Note that these are supported in Rich Edit 4.1 and newer only)

For these, the `CHARRANGE` points to the `HYPERLINK "https://www.example.com"` part, which is hidden and cannot be selected using the `EM_EXSETSEL`. Actually it can be selected on Windows 10. But it cannot be selected on Windows 7, Vista and XP. Sending the `EM_EXSETSEL` to these systems results in selecting a zero-length block just after the hidden part.

So either you have to go back in the rich edit buffer and scan for the link; or use another method to retrieve the clicked text.

In my case, as I have small texts only in the rich edit, I've used the `WM_GETTEXT`. It returns a plain-text version of the rich edit document, but with the friendly name hyperlinks preserved in this form:

```
HYPERLINK "https://www.example.com" Example
```

The `CHARRANGE` points to the URL, strangely including the leading quote:  (`"https://www.example.com`).

But the indexes correspond to a text with a single-character (LF) line separators. While the `WM_GETTEXT` returns the CRLF separators. So you have to convert the text to the LF before extracting the URL using the `CHARRANGE`.

Comment: Thank for the `hyperlink`

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [EM_AUTOURLDETECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you are supposed to get an [EN_LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification, which should be reflected in the `nmhdr.code`. According to Google,

```
#define EN_LINK 0x70B
```

which is 7 * 256 + 11 = 1750 + 42 + 11 = 1803.

Please note that your code misses a check for `nmhdr.code == EN_LINK`.

I'm not sure if the control sends `NM_HOVER` messages at all.

Comment: Thanks, that explains what I saw.