# How set text clickable in richedit

Tags: delphi, clickable, richedit

In internet I found how to recognize url in richedit and make it clickable like a link and go to website.

that is the code to detect web links:

```
var
  mask: Word;
begin
  mask := SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, mask or ENM_LINK);
  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, Integer(True), 0);
end;
```

and this is the code to open link:

```
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;

var
  p: TENLink;
  strURL: string;
begin
  if (Message.Msg = WM_NOTIFY) then
  begin
    if (PNMHDR(Message.lParam).code = EN_LINK) then
    begin
      p := TENLink(Pointer(TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr)^);
      if (p.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then
      begin
        SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, Longint(@(p.chrg)));
        strURL := RichEdit1.SelText;
        ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(strURL), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
      end
    end
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

also i found a code to color the text between parenthesis:

```
procedure HTMLSyntax(Richedit: TRichEdit; TextCol, TagCol, DopCol: TColor);
var
  i, iDop: Integer;
  s: string;
  Col: TColor;
  isTag, isDop: Boolean;
begin
  iDop := 0;
  isDop := False;
  isTag := False;
  Col := TextCol;
  Richedit.SetFocus;

  for i := 0 to Length(Richedit.Text) do
  begin
    Richedit.SelStart := i;
    Richedit.SelLength := 1;
    s := Richedit.SelText;

    if (s = '(') or (s = '{') then
      isTag := True;

    if isTag then
      if (s = '"') then
        if not isDop then
        begin
          iDop := 1;
          isDop := True;
        end
        else
          isDop := False;

    if isTag then
      if isDop then
      begin
        if iDop = 1 then
          Col := DopCol;
      end
      else
        Col := TagCol
      else
        Col := TextCol;

    Richedit.SelAttributes.Color := Col;

    iDop := 0;

    if (s = ')') or (s = '}') then
      isTag := False;
  end;

  Richedit.SelLength := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  HTMLSyntax(RichEdit1, clBlue, clRed, clYELLOW);
  RichEdit1.Lines.EndUpdate;
end;
```

the first two codes automatically detect text that starts with 'www.' and treats that as a web link to '.com'.
my question is how to use the third code which highlights the text in parenthesis and set it like a web link in first code and shows a message instead of opening browser in second code.
to be more clear, suppose there is a scientific text in richedit and you want to give reference at different points like [(19)](https://19).
if the user click that text , a message with full reference address apears.
thanks.

Comment: 1. You should work on your problem and provide more focused question
    with showing what have you done.
    
 2. Clearly you didn't search enough, there are helpful answers right
        here in Stack Over Flow.

I suggest study these links: [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: as @Remy-Lebeau explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480173/detect-click-on-url-in-richedit) link, you can work-around `CN_NOTIFY` message and `WindowProc` property.

Comment: @ArminTaghavizad:  Sadly, there are many qs here which show far less research effort than this one -  see Remy's comment on your deleted answer.